# Subplot is not plotting the actual data, what should I do?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I have a data frame with a related salary to the major.
I am trying to create horizontal bar charts of the majors sorted by salary.
My code looks like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

topTenMajor = df[['Major','Salary']].sort_values('Salary', ascending=False).set_index('Major')
topTenMajor.sort_values('Salary', ascending=True).plot.barh(figsize=(5,10))

ax.set_title('Majors by Salary')
ax.set_xlabel('Salary')
ax.set_ylabel('Majors')
```

However, my chart shows one emptly plots on top with title, x label and y label,
and then a horizontal barchart under the empty plots without title and labels.
Why is this happening?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Please share the figure rather than describing it.

Comment: @Julien sorry just added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barh` will plot in a new figure / axes by default.
Either you need to tell it to plot in the `fig, ax` you created before.
Or you can set title and labels in the active figure automatically created:

```
topTenMajor = df[['Major','Salary']].sort_values('Salary', ascending=False).set_index('Major')
topTenMajor.sort_values('Salary', ascending=True).plot.barh(figsize=(5,10))

plt.title('Majors by Salary')
plt.xlabel('Salary')
plt.ylabel('Majors')
```